# is there any way to move VIP to another resource group in DB2 TSAMP environment?

Tags: db2

Suppose a TSAMP cluster with two databases that use the same virtual IP and IBM. service IP is attached to db1.
Is there any way to move IBM.ServiceIP from db1 to db2 without drop & define the cluster?
thanks

Comment: This is a programming forum. Your question is about system administration. Better suited to dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you tried the `db2haicu` utility to remove this VIP from `db1` and add it to `db2`?

Comment: @Mark Barinstein yes i know that but because of the operational system i need do it without drop and define VIP.

Comment: @mao sory it's my bad. can i move my post to suitable forum or recreate it ? thanks

Comment: @Evan Lock both database resource groups (not instance) with `rgreq -o lock ${dbX-rg}`, use [rmrgmbr](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRM2X_4.1.0/com.ibm.samp.doc_4.1/samprgrmrgmbr.html) to remove the `IBM.ServiceIP` resource from `db1-rg` and `addrgmbr` to add it to `db2-rg`. Unlock both resource groups with `rgreq -o unlock ${dbX-rg}`. This should work, if both `${dbX-rg}` groups are online on the same server, of course.

Comment: @Mark Barinstein let me create a test environment and try it. thank you

Comment: @Mark Barinstein Thank you! It works perfect.